# How to lower the Navigation drawer so header isn't cut off by actionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I know I can make it that the Navigation Header slides over the actionBar but I just want to move the entire Navigation drawer down instead because I want to keep by "Back Pressed" button and actionBar visible at all times. How do I lower the Navigation drawer all together so it appears directly under the actionBar.

Here's what it looks like now, with the Navigation Header being cut off by actionBar:

[image]

Here's my code for Navigation Drawer:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_info"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="#000000"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/color_press_navigation"
    android:id="@+id/Navigation_header"
    >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: you should display drawer layout after the toolbar....in fact you are displaying toolbar inside drawer layout .

Answer (score 9):

Found the answer to be:

android:fitsSystemWindows="false"